# Наследование от обобщенного класса с IEnumerator

Tags: c#, generics, ienumerable, ienumerator

Вопрос больше теоретический. Но буду признателен и за практическое решение, а дальше, на его основе, смогу додумать.

До сего момента плотно с обобщениями работать не приходилось и уперся в то, что второй день не могу внятно сформулировать Гуглу вопрос и, соответственно, получаю ответы как вот сейчас на вопрос "как вставить текст между <> в редакторе стековерфлоу" - ответы про вставку их как угодно и куда угодно, кроме редактора на сайте :)

Возникла задача

1. Реализовать некий базовый класс. При этом поля ID и Value - обобщенные, ID ограничено - IConvertible, IComparable
2. Реализовать коллекцию (наподобие List) для этих элементов, в которой реализованы все необходимые методы работы с элементами
3. Реализовать коллекцию (наподобие Dictionary) для работы с коллекциями из п. 2, а через них и доступ к элементам из п. 1
   (т.е. получается, что пп 2-3 обеспечивают еще и доступ по типу row\column для элемента, но, тем не менее, юзать DataTable или другие встроенные типы - не подходит)

Смысл в том, что элементы содержат все необходимые свойства\методы для разных, но однотипных задача (в основном справочники всякие). И, по задумке - ID может быть цифрой, к которой привязывается Value - строка, или наоборот или ID - строка\цифра\дата - Value класс.

Как следствие - TID, TVаlue элементов указывается так же и для коллекций всех уровней (п.п. 2-3) и, стало быть, если для п.3 создаем `MyDic<string, string>`  то и все остальное, вплоть до элементов, будет этого типа.

В пп. 2-3 реализован интерфейс IEnumerable.

В итоге получается следующее

1. Наследую базовый класс `StrElm : BaseElm<string, string>`
2. Для работы с ним наследую `StrLst : BaseLst<string, string>`

Уже получается чепуха. Т.к. IEnumerable, реализованный в BaseLst, возвращает  `BaseElm<TID, TValue>`, а не StrElm.

При этом компилятор итерацию `foreach(StrElm el in StrLst)` пропускает, в реалтайме Exception приведения типов.

А если var - то возвращает, соотв. `BaseElm<string, string>`, а не StrElm

Вот, собственно, и вопрос. Как бы это обойти.
А, точнее - догадываюсь, что косяк у меня в "архитектуре" оттого, что опыта работы с обобщениями маловато,  а сама задача, с виду, "типовая" - организовать работу с элементами с нужным функционалом и уже вчера была бы решена, если бы типы были заранее определенными.
Поэтому и вопрос более "глобальный" - как это реализуется в случае обобщенных типов и где бы об этом почитать ( или глянуть примеры), но, по возможности, под конкретную эту задачу (увы, перечитать Рихтера или, хотя бы, Троелсена, осмыслить обобщения и написать потому как надо уже не успеваю :) )

Comment: К чему весь этот текст, если у вас вопрос по коду? Хотите что то спросить по коду - покажите код и вашу проблему в нем.

Comment: Для комментария оказалось слишком много. Попробуйте хотя бы псевдокодом показать структуру ваших классов и отношений между ними.

Comment: я не понял зачем делать `BaseLst<string, string>` если можно `BaseLst<StrElm>`

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря не совсем понял что вы хотите, лучше хотя бы псевдокодом показать что вы хотите получить если не знаете как это реализовать на целевом языке, но в комментарии код писать ни разу не здорово, поэтому пусть пока повисит в виде ответа.

По описанию вам вероятно нужно что-то такое

```
class BaseType<TId, TValue> where TId : struct, IConvertible, IComparable
{
    public TId Id { get; set; }
    public TValue Value { get; set; }
    //ваша дополнительная логика
}

class CustomList<TElem, TId, TValue> : List<TElem> 
    where TId : struct, IConvertible, IComparable
    where TElem : BaseType<TId, TValue> 

{ 
    //ваша дополнительная логика
}

class CustomDictionary<TKey, TDictVAlue, TElem,  TId, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TElem> 
    where TId : struct, IConvertible, IComparable
    where TElem : BaseType<TId, TValue> 
    where TDictVAlue : CustomList<TElem, TId, TValue>
{
    //ваша дополнительная логика
}
```

Но это такое себе решение и действительно попахивает проблемами в архитектуре. Если что-то непонятно - добавлю уточнения, если совсем не попал - совсем удалю.